# .htaccess mod_rewrite exchange random word for folder name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get the following url entered into the address bar:

`http://localhost/ci/page/random/3`

*random* could be anything, but will be the page title and used only for SEO purposes.
 and *3* could be any numeric value, but is used to retrieve a db record.

to be rewritten as this
`http://localhost/ci/page/index/3`

I tried the following in the .htaccess but didn't work:
`RewriteRule ^(?)$ /page/index/$1 [L]`

here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
RewriteRule ^page$ /index/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?)$ /page/index/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is `/random` always only _one_ level, or could it be `/random/alsorandom/3` ?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski only one level

Comment: Also, do you have any other `RewriteRule` in addition to this one? This looks like it's going into CodeIgniter or something. mod_rewrite is highly order-sensitive, so please post any other rules you have.

Comment: And last question: What directory is your .htaccess in? Is `/ci` a real directory in the filesystem?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski /ci is the folder that the website is in. htaccess is in the root of that same folder: http://localhost/ci/htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Because I couldn't get this to work the way i wanted, I changed the URL structure from:
`http://localhost/ci/page/random/3`

to
`http://localhost/ci/page/3/random`

No 404 any more :-)